# Decrease Width of RPi Zero

Tags: pi-zero, case

The Raspberry Pi Zero has dimensions of approximately: 2.6" x 1.2" x 0.2"

I need the 2.6" side to measure no more than 2.5" for it to fit into my container.

Is there enough "extra" board to where I can safely file/sand down the sides to achieve this maximum width?

Comment: Interesting question and I'd go with @goldilocks answer below with one possible get out: can you slot the board in at an angle into the container, my trigonometry is too rusty from disuse to actually do the maths but if one of the sides with the camera or microSD card is raised then the _length_ needed to accommodate it will reduce - at the expense of needing more _height_.  It will also put all the connectors down the other sides at a slant and not all on the same level, and finally it will make mounting it quite awkward.  All in all some quite ugly hackery but if there is no other way...!

Comment: @SlySven That's a good idea. I had planned to stuff a battery underneath or above the Zero in the container, so putting it all in at an angle might prove difficult. I'm considering actually cutting off the camera connector (and part of the board around it), since it seems to rob quite a bit of space... however that risks destroying the Zero, so I'll need to get a few before experimenting ;-P

Comment: Oh, and another thing - is there a case slot for the microSD card - otherwise it __might just__ project out of the edge of the PWB I believe! 8-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  As you can see below, on the Zero v 1.3 the camera connector extends completely to one end and the SD card holder to within a mm of the other -- and slightly outside that line there's a resistor (?) mounted (immediately below the holder in the picture), so you probably do not want to file anything off.

Looking at one in my hand I'd say if you removed the clip from the camera port first, you might be able to take a millimeter off that side and 0.5 mm off the other.  Unfortunately this is less than 1/16" total.

The 2.6" measurement is also accurate.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for doing the legwork. I am willing to remove components from the board, but seems I'll still be too wide. I don't have a Zero yet, so wanted to see if it was possible before acquiring one.

Comment: You might consider picking up an older style Zero, if still available. It doesn't have the camera connector and hence might save you a millimeter or two.

Comment: @PhilB. That might be an idea. Hardware specs look identical, except the camera connector. I'm considering getting a couple v1.3 Zero's and just hacking off the camera connector and surrounding board, but that may wreck the board depending on what traces are passing through that area, so experimentation is needed!

Comment: There are some helpful xrays of pi zeros that might save a few bin efforts: https://www.flickr.com/photos/ultrapurple/26487109633 Good luck! Looks busy in there.

Comment: Looking at that X-ray image and remembering that the spacing of the 40-pin header is 0.1 inch I can't see that you can hack that much of each end, there are via and it is not clear if they are buried or not.